# Is it possible to refresh a php site when a post request is detected?

Tags: php

Let say a sensor is sending data to my php-dashboard via post requests. Is it possible to update them live on my page or do I need javascript for that?

Comment: You will need javascript for that while polling another URL that responds in JSON with any changes that need to occur to your dashboard, but this isn't a tutorial site so hopefully, that pushes you in the right direction, and feel free to come back and show us what you've tried and where you're stuck. Good luck

Comment: thank you :) i already have an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a live link between anyone looking at your dashboard and mutating data in your database or other data source, php alone is most likely not going to work. Have a look into websockets, though php has an implementation I have yet to encounter one that is production ready.

Comment: OP barely know's what is what and you're throwing him into websockets lol.

Comment: I don't like to assume what people do or don't know. But I fear you may be correct.

Comment: still helpful thanks, i have another idea with js ajax, gonna try that today.